# DFS time-complexity with non-constant operation

Tags: c++, time-complexity, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

While traversing in depth-first search fashion, what is the time complexity if there is a non-constant operation?

For example below, `node[child]` is a `set<int>` so `erase()` has run time of `O(log n)` where `n` is the number of vertices.

```cpp
        while(!q.empty()) { // O(n)
            auto parent = q.front();
            q.pop_front();
            for(auto& child : node[parent]) { // O(e * log n)
                if(!isVisited[child]) {
                    isVisited[child] = true;
                    q.push_front(child);
                    node[child].erase(parent); // O(log n)
                } else {
                    return false;   
                }
            }

        }
```

Would the total runtime then be `O(n + e * log n)` where `e` is the number of edges?

The problem is from https://leetcode.com/problems/graph-valid-tree

**Update**: Here is the accepted submission https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/518475470/

Comment: Side-note: when using Big-O notation, only the most significant order-of-magnitude matters, so `O( n + e * log n )` can be simplified as `O( e * log n )`

Comment: What is the shape of the graph you're traversing? Is the graph always an acyclic tree? If so then you don't need to track visited nodes in a hashset, just use a stack.

Comment: `n` isn't constant in the entire graph, is it? If `n` varies per-node then things get complicated - but why can't `erase` be a constant-time operation that simply marks a node as invalid and you perform actual cleanup afterwards?

Comment: For the benefit of the rest of us that don't have LeetCode accounts, please post the full types of `q` and `isVisited`. Also, why are you using `set<>` instead of `unordered_set<>`?

Comment: What would the complexity be if there were no C++?  You are relying on C++ coding to determine the complexity -- is this what you should be doing?  As stated, that "complexity" changes if you used the proper data structure, i.e. `unordered_set` instead of `set`.  So are you asking about the general algorithmic complexity (which does not rely on any programming language)?

Comment: @Dai "`O( n + e * log n )` can be simplified as `O( e * log n )`". Not strictly true. You can have fewer edges than nodes if the graph isn't connected.

Comment: I guess that answers it, for each edge there is an `log(n)` operation while nodes are traversed only once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a connected graph, yes, as you surmised the overall complexity for big O notation would be

```
O (E logN)
```

It is customary to use E and V for the collection of edges and vertices. ei for instance is for a particular edge. |E| is for the number of edges, but in context E can be used instead of |E|.